# Correct way how to register custom IStateSerializer<T>

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Where exactly the registration of a custom IStateSerializer during lifetime of StatefulService should take place in order to be effective?

```
internal sealed class Automat : StatefulService
{
    public Automat(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var ok = this.StateManager.TryAddStateSerializer(new DeviceStateSerializer());
        if (!ok)
        {
            Log.FailedToRegisterStateSerializer();
            throw new Exception("Failed to register state serializer.");
        }

        ...
    }
}

public sealed class DeviceStateSerializer : IStateSerializer<DeviceState>
{ ... }
```

Shortly after deployment the health event *Partition is in quorum loss. (System.FM)* is reported and futher down the line the secondary instances of stateful service will emit warnings:

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2019-04-10T13:08:10.2801059+02:00",
  "ProviderName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric",
  "Id": 54429,
  "Message": "EventName: StatefulReplicaNewHealthReport Category: Health Partition=9396223e-01be-44fa-9b19-2438a5caec80 StatefulReplica=131993679124719148 InstanceId=131993679124719149 SourceId=System.RA Property=ReplicaOpenStatus HealthState=Warning TTL=922337203685477ms SequenceNumber=131993680683950343 Description='Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_3. API call: IStatefulServiceReplica.Open(); Error = System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException (-2146233088)
    Type 'SmartGrid.Automat.Contracts.DeviceState' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.RecoveryManager.PerformRecoveryAsync(RecoveredOrCopiedCheckpointLsn recoveredOrCopiedCheckpointLsn, OperationProcessor recordsProcessor, CheckpointManager checkpointManager, TransactionManager transactionManager, LogRecordsDispatcher logRecordsDispatcher, ReplicatedLogManager replicatedLogManager)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator.PerformRecoveryAsync(RecoveryInformation recoveryInformation)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, TransactionalReplicatorSettings transactionalReplicatorSettings)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionalReplicator.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, TransactionalReplicatorSettings transactionalReplicatorSettings)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.StatefulServiceReplica.System.Fabric.IStatefulServiceReplica.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, IStatefulServicePartition partitionObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManagerImpl.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IStateProviderReplica.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, IStatefulServicePartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulServiceReplicaAdapter.System.Fabric.IStatefulServiceReplica.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, IStatefulServicePartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    For more information see: http://aka.ms/sfhealth' RemoveWhenExpired=False SourceUTCTimestamp=04/10/2019 13:07:48 ",
  "ProcessId": 19324,
  "Level": "Informational",
  "Keywords": "0x4000000000000001",
  "EventName": "HM",
  "ActivityID": null,
  "RelatedActivityID": null,
  "Payload": {
    "eventName": "StatefulReplicaNewHealthReport",
    "category": "Health",
    "eventInstanceId": "\"9bd354b7-0ab8-4a3d-99ce-48dbf3361432\"",
    "partitionId": "\"9396223e-01be-44fa-9b19-2438a5caec80\"",
    "replicaId": 131993679124719148,
    "replicaInstanceId": 131993679124719149,
    "sourceId": "System.RA",
    "property": "ReplicaOpenStatus",
    "healthState": 2,
    "TTLtimespan": 922337203685477,
    "sequenceNumber": 131993680683950343,
    "description": "Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_3. API call: IStatefulServiceReplica.Open(); Error = System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException (-2146233088)
      Type 'SmartGrid.Automat.Contracts.DeviceState' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.RecoveryManager.PerformRecoveryAsync(RecoveredOrCopiedCheckpointLsn recoveredOrCopiedCheckpointLsn, OperationProcessor recordsProcessor, CheckpointManager checkpointManager, TransactionManager transactionManager, LogRecordsDispatcher logRecordsDispatcher, ReplicatedLogManager replicatedLogManager)
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator.PerformRecoveryAsync(RecoveryInformation recoveryInformation)
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, TransactionalReplicatorSettings transactionalReplicatorSettings)
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionalReplicator.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, TransactionalReplicatorSettings transactionalReplicatorSettings)
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.StatefulServiceReplica.System.Fabric.IStatefulServiceReplica.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, IStatefulServicePartition partitionObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManagerImpl.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IStateProviderReplica.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, IStatefulServicePartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulServiceReplicaAdapter.System.Fabric.IStatefulServiceReplica.OpenAsync(ReplicaOpenMode openMode, IStatefulServicePartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      For more information see: http://aka.ms/sfhealth",
    "removeWhenExpired": false,
    "sourceUtcTimestamp": "\"\/Date(1554894468395)\/\""
  }
}
```

I think it is trying to deserialize DeviceState by using fallback to DataContractSerializer and not registered DeviceStateSerializer.

- Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 3.3.644
- Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.3.644
- Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data 3.3.644

Answer (score 0):

The state serializer registration has to be in the ctor, than it works.

```
public Automat(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
{
    var ok = this.StateManager.TryAddStateSerializer(new DeviceStateSerializer());
    if (!ok)
    {
        Log.FailedToRegisterStateSerializer();
    }
}
```